# Cipher functions:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:DATA_NOT_MULTIPLE_OF_BLOCK_LENGTH

Tags: android, encryption, aes

Im trying to implement AES in an Android application. The server is a PHP server.

This is the AES code :

```
public class AES{

private String SecretKey = "89432hjfsd891787";
private String iv = "fedcba9876543210";
private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
private Cipher cipher;

public AES()
{
    ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
    keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public byte[] encrypt(String text) throws Exception
{
    if(text == null || text.length() == 0)
        throw new Exception("Empty string");

    byte[] encrypted = null;

    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return encrypted;
}

public byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception
{
    if(code == null || code.length() == 0)
        throw new Exception("Empty string");

    byte[] decrypted = null;

    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

        decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return decrypted;
}



public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data)
{
    if (data==null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    int len = data.length;
    String str = "";
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if ((data[i]&0xFF)<16)
            str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
        else
            str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
    }
    return str;
}


public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
    if (str==null) {
        return null;
    } else if (str.length() < 2) {
        return null;
    } else {
        int len = str.length() / 2;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}

private static String padString(String source)
{
    char paddingChar = ' ';
    int size = 16;
    int x = source.length() % size;
    int padLength = size - x;
    for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++) {
        source += paddingChar;
    }
    return source;
}
}
```

I get an error while decrypting the incoming string : Cipher functions:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:DATA_NOT_MULTIPLE_OF_BLOCK_LENGTH

How do i go about this?

Comment: Even with your problem fixed, this code is insecure and should not be used.

Comment: What is the size of `hexToBytes(code)`? Hint: assign to local variable first, don't perform decoding and decrypting on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Manually padding the `String` representation of the plaintext with spaces is not a good padding mechanism. Instead, you should use `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` which will handle the padding as prescribed in PKCS #5/#7.

You should also:

1. generate a unique IV per encryption operation rather than re-using the same value for all messages
2. Use an authenticated mode of operation (`GCM`, `HMAC/SHA-256` MAC over cipher text, etc.)
3. Store the key in hexadecimal representation of the raw bytes rather than an ASCII/UTF-8 String encoding (not specified in your code)
4. Encode the cipher text in Base64 or Hex before serializing/transmitting. Encoding errors can contribute to padding exceptions during decryption.

Comment: The single iteration SHA-256 digest is not a strong KDF, and the cipher text output isn't Base64 encoded, but this is a [sufficient example](https://gist.github.com/itarato/abef95871756970a9dad) of #1 and `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`.